# Doohan Itank electric bike ,no display ,headlight flash,s ,front signal lights not working

Tags: electrical

Have a electric bike Manufactured by Doohan (China)it has a 60 volt bosh motor. 60 volt 26 amp lithium battery pack ...also has a DC-DC converter ,for lights and display .. the Doohan only have 1 outlet here in the Philippines. and have not been able to get anyone to look at the bike and by all accounts they do not have spare parts in this county anyway. The motor works fine and always has, but since day one the display has always been hit and miss , had to unplug battery and reconnect sometimes to get display to work but last few weeks no display and headlight only flash,s, front side lights do not turn on .(all rear lights work ,tail,signal,stop.all working .) no signal at front or side lights only headlight flash,s (main beam and dipped same)all wiring has been checked and all electrical plugs seem to be okay all been cleaned with electronic cleaner. and re plugged back together, some times after travelling for 30 to 45 minutes display comes back on ,but after resting and recharging battery ,display goes off again . could this be the DC-DC controller or bad wiring ,how can I check it.??

Comment: You say "all wiring has been checked" - by who? And why not get it checked again? This time the fault may be visible or traceable...

Comment: Was checked by me and all wiring has no damage to it and all plugs have no bent connectors , this bike was new 3 months ago and has only done 700 km has been kept in garage since new and has not been used in the rain.. in fact it has not rained here since Xmas. cannot get wiring tested because no one in the Philippines has enough knowledge to be able to test it . Have emailed the factory who made it and they are suggesting its the DC-DC converter  .Thats why I need help to check out if it is that ,they do not give any clue how to do the testing though ...

Comment: If the motor is Bosch, who makes the controller - they may have a diagram etc

Comment: The controller has a Doohan sticker on with serial number printed on it . .The DC-DC controller is separate to the controller not integrated , that is out of site and cannot see who manufactured that ,without removing all the front of the bikes plastic covers .

Comment: still no answer , even the place I bought it from cannot find what is wrong ..been there 2 weeks now .!!

Comment: how do you charge your battery?
i understand you connect charger cable to your scooter first, then you plug to the mains.
or else the display goes wonky.
hope this helps